# Exclusion script in Exactatrget

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am new to AMPSCRIPT and want to write a Exclusion script to suppress the first entry in my sample DE. I Want to suppress the emails for contact with `Active = True` and `Registered = True`. How to write a exclusion script to meet both the criteria. Below is the code i am using but unable to figure out how to include both my criteria.

```
%%[ RowCount(LookupRows("Exclude_Customers", "EmailAddress",??))>0 ]%%
```

Refer to the DE screenshot below. `Exclude_Customers` is my DE name.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this -- just add extra name/value pairs in your [LookupRows()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/AMPscript_Syntax_Guide/Data_Extension_AMPscript_Functions#LookupRows) function.

```
%%[ RowCount(LookupRows("Exclude_Customers", "Active","TRUE","Registered","TRUE"))>0 ]%%
```

Documentation: [LookupRows()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/AMPscript_Syntax_Guide/Data_Extension_AMPscript_Functions#LookupRows)

Answer (score 0):

Is this "Exclude_Customers" DE your targeted DE? If yes you can do something like this:

```
IF [Active] == "TRUE" AND [Registered] == "TRUE" THEN
    RaiseError("Customer Active and Registered", true)
ENDIF
```

If it's not then try something like this:

```
VAR @email, @matches

SET @email = [Email] //Assign email from targeted data extension
SET @matches = LookupRows("Exclude_Customers", "EmailAddress", @email, "Active", "TRUE", "Registered", "TRUE")

IF RowCount(@matches) > 0 THEN
    RaiseError("Customer Active and Registered", true)
ENDIF
```

Do you need to do it with Ampscript? I think it would be better to exclude them with query.

Comment: I want to use the exclusion script in Journey builder send emails so that it  suppresses the email for contact with Active = True and Registered = True. with values . Also "Exclude_Customers' is my targeted DE. Do i need to use your 1st query only or the 1st query need to be included in my sample code as condition statement.   %%[ RowCount(LookupRows("Exclude_Customers", "EmailAddress",??))>0 ]%%

Comment: While using raiseError() to munch the send will effectively exclude a subscriber, it still counts as a send from a billing perspective.