# Suppression List in Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to add amp script code or ssjs script code in suppression list in Exact target? If possible How? Guide me the steps

If AMPscript code can be used in microsites and landing pages, can it be used in suppression list while sending the mail as well?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please clarify and add this information to your question. Just to make sure, here is the documentation on [Suppression Lists](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/)

Comment: @MarkusSlabina , if amp scripts code can be used in microsite and landing page like that, amp scripts code can be used in suppression list while sending the mail

Comment: A suppression list does not have an area where you can type any SSJS or Ampscript. You cannot type Ampscript in a Suppression List any more than you can type one in a data extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppression Lists don't have anything in common with emails, microsites and landing pages where you can use AMPscript. If you are talking about using AMPscript in emails, you are sending when using Suppression Lists, this sure is possible.

> A suppression list is a list of subscribers that you don't want to receive your communications.
> (Source: [Marketing Cloud documentation about Suppression Lists](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/))

**Further basic information on the related topics:**

- [Suppression Lists](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/)
- [Create a Suppression List](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/create_a_suppression_list/)
- [AMPscript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/)
- [Get Started With AMPscript](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is called an '[exclusion script](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213279&type=1)' ([some more info](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/)) The documentation via SFMC is limited (as usual), but it should be a free add-on to your account, you just need to contact your Rep or support to turn it on.

**Sample Exclusion script:**

```
Rowcount(LookupRows('suppression_DE', 'EmailAddress', emailaddr)) > 0
```

**Here are a couple samples in SFSE about exclusion scripts:**

- [Exclusion script in Exactatrget](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128903/exclusion-script-in-exactatrget)
- [Exclusion Script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111394/exclusion-script)
- [Exclusion Script inside Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/178849/36218)
- [Exclusion Script for Journey Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/177977/36218)